# Bijection between Standard Young Tableaux of height $\leq 2$ and $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$-element subsets of $[n]$.

Tags: combinatorics, young-tableaux

In OEIS sequence [A001405](https://oeis.org/A001405), Mike Zabrocki claims that the number of Standard Young Tableaux of length $\leq 2$ is equal to $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$.

I haven't been able to conjure up a bijection. Is there a standard bijection to know about?

Comment: I think it must have to do with ballot sequences.  See the two notes by Joerg Arndt on [A000085](https://oeis.org/A000085).

Comment: There's a (non-bijective) proof here: http://amsacta.unibo.it/2443/1/bounded_height.pdf ; it also contains a reference to what seems to be the original representation-theoretic proof.